# What is the meaning of ^ symbol for SPX

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges, market-indexes, equity

I've seen symbols SPX and ^SPX, is there any significance for the symbol "^"?

Comment: The "^" prefix tells the quotation system to retrieve a quote for an index rather than a quote for a tradeable security.  A quote for an index with be of a different format and source from a quote for a traded security.  For example, ^SPX, ^DJI, etc... do not include things like bid and offer, company profiles, etc....

Comment: @NickR You’ve got a good answer here, so [post it as an answer, not a comment](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/10997).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data providers  and brokers use a different syntax for symbols.  The caret means nothing.

Where it gets crazy is preferred stocks where there about a dozen conventions where there is a letter for the issue:

XYZ-A

XYZ_A

XYZ^A

XYZ+A

XYX.A

XYZprA

XYZ.prA

XYZ/A

XYZ'A

XYZ prA

XYZ_PA

etc.

I have no clue why they don'standardize this.